# How to make react app save the selected language when i m choosing languages

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-i18next

I want the input to store the selected languages ​​so I can change the language in the selector. I want the language change to be reflected in the entire application,[image]

```js
<SelectsLanguages
                            languages={languages}
                            
                            onChange={languages => setState(prev => ({...prev, user__languages : languages}))}
                            value={state.user__languages}
                            name="user__languages"
                            
                        />
```

```css
 const [state, setState] = useState(
        { user__languages: urlParams.get('user__languages') || ""
 
 
    }
    );
 
 const onSubmit = () => {
 
 const params =
  `&${state.user__languages.length ? state.user__languages : '' }`;
     })
        }
```

Comment: You could use a state management library, like redux or React Context, in order to manage global states.

Comment: You need to save th selected state and save it in Some global state.
then take this state and pass that state to the global css.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Cookies for that
There is the Module **universal-cookie** for react

```
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
const cookies = new Cookies();
cookies.set('language', state.user__languages', { path: '/' }); //set cookie
console.log(cookies.get('language')); //read cookie
```